# Run query in parallel in Spark Databricks

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, databricks

I’m developing a query that has about 1000 lines, I’m  using it for data quality. Basically, this query gets about 10 metrics on each column (SUM, AVG, STDDEV, PERCENTILE, MIN, MAX, COUNT,…). The problem is, some DataFrames has more then 100 columns. I tried two approaches to solve this problem.

First one is running a lot of small queries and union them all in a single DataFrame using spark SQL, like:

```
SELECT AVG (col1) as metric from table
UNION ALL 
SELECT MAX (col1) as metric from table
UNION ALL
SELECT MIN (col1) as metric from table
UNION ALL 
SELECT STDDEV (col1) as metric from table
UNION ALL
SELECT AVG (col2) as metric from table
UNION ALL 
SELECT MAX (col2) as metric from table
UNION ALL
SELECT MIN (col2) as metric from table
UNION ALL 
SELECT STDDEV (col2) as metric from table
…
SELECT STDDEV (col100) as metric from table
```

I cached my table DataFrame. Although, this query runs eternally on my cluster.

My second approach was:

```
SELECT AVG (col1) as avgcol1,
       MAX (col1) as maxcol1,
       MIN (col1) as mincol1,
       STDDEV (col1) as stddevcol1,
       AVG (col2) as avgcol2,
       MAX (col2) as maxcol2,
       MIN (col2) as mincol2,
       STDDEV (col2) as stddevcol2,
       …
FROM table
```

This approach also runs eternally on my cluster.

My cluster has 1 driver and 1 worker (4 cores and 8GB each).

**My doubt is**: Can I solve my performance problem without scaling my cluster? If so, what is the best approach to solve this problem?

I thought to use ThreadPool on Databricks to solve this performance issue. But, since spark is distributed is ThreadPool the best approach?

Or should I use spark paralelism (partition column, upperBound, lowerBound and numPartitions) to solve that?

NOTE: In some metrics I use subquerys with window functions (on string type columns)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to do some data profiling against the data , Instead of using spark sql query simple way you can use following commands .

```
describe: count, mean, stddev, min, max
summary: describe + interquartile range (IQR)
```

[image]

```
display(fixed_price_df.describe())
display(fixed_price_df.summary())
```

Comment: Your answer solve the problem partially. There are some custom metrics on string columns that  `describe + summary` does not solve. But, summary has a nice performance, so I’ll accept it as correct.

Comment: thanks . What additional information you need in this case .

Comment: Date metrics and `mode`

Comment: Please check this will help you on this : date metrics # Calculate date metrics
date_metrics = df.select(
    min("date_column").alias("min_date"),
    max("date_column").alias("max_date"),
    avg(unix_timestamp("date_column")).alias("avg_date_unix_timestamp")
)

date_metrics.show() | since mode is max value of the particular column already we have solutions